# How to check if Path2D intersect with Line?

Tags: java

How do i check if Path2D intersects with line2d.

I should iterate through all path segments (lines, curves,...) and check if each intersects with line (defined by X1,Y1 and X2, Y2). but how to itterate?

It has to be precise so no boundary or bounding box.

Comment: Do you want to know where it intersects or only if it does intersect?

Comment: Could you use [`Path2D#intersects(x, y, width, height)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#intersects(double,%20double,%20double,%20double))?

Comment: if it intersects.
I can't use intersects method because it checks it path intersects with rectangle (defined by x,y,w and h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a simple path2D (rectangle, triangle) with straight segments (no curves) this works:

```
public static boolean intersects(Path2D.Double path, Line2D line) {
    double x1 = -1 ,y1 = -1 , x2= -1, y2 = -1;
    for (PathIterator pi = path.getPathIterator(null); !pi.isDone(); pi.next()) 
    {
        double[] coordinates = new double[6];
        switch (pi.currentSegment(coordinates))
        {
        case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
        case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
        {
            if(x1 == -1 && y1 == -1 )
            {
                x1= coordinates[0];
                y1= coordinates[1];
                break;
            }               
            if(x2 == -1 && y2 == -1)
            {
                x2= coordinates[0];             
                y2= coordinates[1];
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        if(x1 != -1 && y1 != -1 && x2 != -1 && y2 != -1)
        {
            Line2D segment = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            if (segment.intersectsLine(line)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            x1 = -1;
            y1 = -1;
            x2 = -1;
            y2 = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It could probably be solved more elegantly, and should cover SEG_CLOSE as well, but in principle, this is the way to go. When using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#getPathIterator-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-double- you don't even have to cope with curves.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is a more robust version of the algorithm from BorisT that also takes into consideration SEG_CLOSE.

```
static boolean intersects(Line2D.Double line, Path2D.Double path) {
  if (!navigableArea.contains(line.getP1()) || !navigableArea.contains(line.getP2()))
    return false;
  Point2D.Double start = null;
  Point2D.Double point1 = null;
  Point2D.Double point2 = null;
  for (PathIterator pi = navigableArea.getPathIterator(null); !pi.isDone(); pi.next()) {
    double[] coordinates = new double[6];
    switch (pi.currentSegment(coordinates)) {
    case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
      point2 = new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
      point1 = null;
      start = (Point2D.Double) point2.clone();
      break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
      point1 = point2;
      point2 = new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
      break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
      point1 = point2;
      point2 = start;
      break;
    }
    if (point1 != null) {
      Line2D segment = new Line2D.Double(point1, point2);
      if (segment.intersectsLine(line))
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Considering that `navigableArea` (undefined) is `path` (unused). This early check is terribly wrong and should be removed (or modified). Example: The line (0, 1)->(2, 1) obviously intersects the path (0, 0)->(1, 2)->(2, 0) but because of this check the method would return false. The only one reliable early check returning false I can quickly think of is `path.getBounds2D().intersects(line.getBounds2D())` but I'm not even sure it's worth the cost (of path.getBounds2D()).